# Windows 8 phone app design in photoshop

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows

I'm working on the design for a windows 8 app, with a team of developers.We have finalized most of the screens for the app, the developer informed me to do the mockup of the entire app in photoshop to be presented to him and the screen size should be 480 x 800. ( right now sitting at 480 x 1800 due to scroll in page)

I have been informed to optimize the mockup for the other 2 remaining screen sizes **768 x 1280** and **720 x 1280** is this required? wouldnt this be covered in development stage.

From my present html5 and css knowledge building small static websites, width 100% in a container with width wouldnt fix this?

As the design is following the guidelines with grids i made from the guidlines pdf i had set it up for 480 x 800 now with two new screen size how can i go about this?

Can i change the canvas size in photoshop and resize all the elements?.

Please let me know if there is anyway possible to get hands on - **SplashScreenImage.Screen-WXGA.jpg** , **SplashScreenImage.Screen-720p.jpg** so i can overlay the jpg in photoshop and create grid i have windows 7 not able to install SDK to get these 2 images.

Comment: `I have been informed to optimize the mockup for the other 2 remaining screen sizes 768 x 1280 and 720 x 1280 is this required? wouldnt this be covered in development stage.` Why aren't you asking the developers directly? And yes, the scaling could be done automatically, but with a loss of quality if some pictures need to be stretched

Answer (score 0):

Mockups for other resolutions would be (almost) the same. There is automatic scaling. The only difference is that 720p resolution screens represent scaled 480x853 resolution, which is almost never any problem (if you have scrollable pages, like you described, the developer has to only make sure that the scrollable component is the one to be expandable in height).

See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206974%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

The only problems are images. The advice (of the above source) is to use the highest scale, that is for images of size 100x100 on 480x800 screen, use files of 160x160 size.